# Linux: Create a user than can access other users' files

Tags: centos

I'm trying to have a mother user, with the root directory `/home/user1` and have the rest of the users in `/home/user1/users`. How can I make it so the users still own their files, but the user `user1` is still able to read/write/execute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user could be a member of their own self-name group.  And the "mother user" could be a member of each of those user groups.
Then files created by users would have to be chmod 66? for files and 77? for directories. and the mother-user would have access to all the other user files.

One exception to the 66?/77? chmods would of course have to be .ssh directory for each user if they are going to use ssh.  Otherwise SSH (for security reasons) would ignore anything in the .ssh directories (been there, done that).

Comment: What is happening now though is that the users that were created in user1's home directory are denied access to the directory, but user1 can't access the directory either. Meaning that user1 cannot access /home/user1/newuser and newuser cannot access that directory either.

Comment: Instead of nesting the actual directories in each other, I would have all the users be off of /home, and just have the mother-user be "just another user" with their own directory off of /home. Sometimes nesting directories has unintended consequences.

Comment: @hexacyanide If you're needing additional input, I'm still here to help.

Answer (score 0):

you could always use access control `setfacl` for this.

http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/setfacl/